# Docker networking and ports

Tags: sockets, tcp, proxy, docker, network-protocols

I am hoping some can try help me to understand and explain what TCP port range and Network protocols Docker is using in order for me to achieve what I am trying to do.

My situation is I have created a docker ***proxy-container*** that exposes ***80:80*** and ***443:443*** this proxy-container then redirects traffic to another container (Lets call it ***container-apache***) on the same server using a non standard ports for instance ***10300:80***. The proxy redirect works well and I am achieving what I need to up until this point.

However when I expose the webserver the proxy-container to the world I am only able to access the apache-container if in my firewall allows all TCP ports and protocols. If I just allow HTTP/S or if i create a customer service that exposes only the 10300 I cannot access the apache-container and I do not want to expose all ports and protocols on this webserver.

Does anyone know which are the least amount of services or just service that needs to be exposed in order for this to work.

I am not sure if my question is clear. If anyone is having a similar problem, knows how to solve this or has some insights I would really appreciate it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure *proxy-container* using internal network IPs of docker (e.g. 172.10.xxx.xxx). But, do you need some tool that discovery instances that running or inspect and rebuild *proxy-container*.

Also you can run *container-apache* with **--name** docker argument and run container-proxy with **--link** argument to docker add in *container-proxy* in hosts file the conainer-apache name. Example, in you proxy reverse configuration, you use *webapp1* as container-apache name server.

```
$docker run -d --name apache1 container-apache

$docker run -d --link apache:webapp1enter container-proxy
```